# Using Bitmap for saving image to Gallery in Android application with camera app

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have problems when i use some code from [Capture Image from Camera and Display in Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991319/capture-image-from-camera-and-display-in-activity) and https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

First, this is in MainActivity.java. I create onClickevent when user press button "snap"

```
 Button snap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    snap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent start_cam = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File path = null;
            try {
                path = createImageFile();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if(path!=null) {
                start_cam.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(path));
                startActivityForResult(start_cam, 1);
            }

        }

    });
```

Next, i add createImageFile() method

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  // prefix
            ".jpg",         // suffix
            storageDir      // directory
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    root_file = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Last part, I add onActivityResult()

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            m = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(root_file));
            try {
                view.setImageBitmap(m);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I also add heading in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

After, i use this feature in android emulator API19 Nexus_one API19 (take a photo). The dialog appears and said "java.lang.nullPointerException".

I don't know why this problem appears. I think it may be my emulator or code.

Comment: check with real device

Comment: @sasikumar Unfortunately, my android device is 4.2.2  ( My code sets for Kitkat or above) = . =a. Have you ever faced like this problem before?

Comment: @sasikumar Thank you for your advice, i will try with real device. :)

Comment: yes its absolute path problem...

Comment: `and said "java.lang.nullPointerException".`. It not only said that. It also told you the line where the statement was that caused this exception. Don't trow away that importand info! DOuble click on the the logcat message and you will end up in the code.

Comment: @sasikumar about this  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES); ??

Comment: @greenapps I find that it appear in  view.setImageBitmap(m); ;(

Comment: Ok. So then tell what you think is the pointer that is null..

Comment: @greenapps According to Mr.sasikumar has faced, i think it's about my path ?

Comment: check image.getAbsolutePath();

Comment: No `view`  is null. Try this: `if ( view==null) Toast( .,.."OMG view==null", ...)else view.setImageBitmap(m);`.

Comment: refer this you will get some idea http://www.limbaniandroid.com/2014/03/how-to-get-absolute-path-when-select.html

Comment: Roger that, i will try and will be back for showing the result. :)))

Comment: @greenapps yes, i use condition 'if(view==null)' and it appears OMGGGGGGG. for about path it shows '/storage/sdcard/Pictures/.......(file name).......jpg'

Comment: So view== null. Then you know what to do.

Comment: I should create 'ImageView' so that is solution right ?

Comment: @greenapps Ok, it shows in my first screen. Unfortunately, it isn't send to gallery in my android emulator = . = ... wahh, it may be new problem occure.